# Filtering WooCommerce Variable and Simples Products using get_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom `get_posts()` query that loads Simple and Variable products, I am posting my code that works when I am filtering simple products **by price** but variable products use a different price field which should be `variable_regular_price[$key]` however... If I just use it, it doesn't work, any idea of how to filter variable and simples products **by price** using the WordPress get_posts() function?

Current code that works for Simple products:

```
    if(!empty($_GET["price"])){
        if($_GET["price"] == 1){
            $min = 0;
            $max = 99;
        }elseif($_GET["price"] == 2){
            $min = 100;
            $max = 199;
        }elseif($_GET["price"] == 3){
            $min = 200;
            $max = 299;
        }elseif($_GET["price"] == 4){
            $min = 300;
        }
        array_push($filter, array('key' => '_regular_price', 'type' => 'NUMERIC', 'value' => $min, 'compare' => '>='));
        if($_GET["price"] != 4){ //there is no limit when is $300+
            array_push($filter, array('key' => '_regular_price', 'type' => 'NUMERIC', 'value' => $max, 'compare' => '<='));
        }
    }

    $filters = array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array('taxonomy' => 'product_type', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $product_type, 'operator' => 'IN'),
                        array('taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'approved', 'operator' => 'IN'),
                        array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $product_cat, 'operator' => 'IN')
                    ),
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        $filter)
                );
    $rs = get_posts($filters);
```

I tried to use a field I found in the back-end but it didn't work. I am expecting to filter SIMPLE and VARIABLE products by using get_posts();